# Am I able to mark mines with the bottom row of 3's?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, minesweeper

Am I able to use the bottom row of 3's to know what some of the squares around it are?

[image: minesweeper]

Comment: How many squares would you require for an answer?

Comment: Any amount @bobble

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes:

[image: image with marked letters]

Consider the four boxed cells here.

The 3 above C tells you that *at least one* of B and C has a mine. But the 3 above B can only accept one more mine! Therefore there is exactly one mine in {B,C}... and so A is safe, and D is a mine.

(You can also do a similar trick with the 2 and 1 just to the right of the 3s!)

Comment: Just curious, what about the 2 and 1? I can only deduce that the cell below the rightmost 2 is safe. Is that all?

Comment: @justhalf Yes, that's all I had.